# How does the angularjs.forEach() work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have the object :

```js
var obj = {
     a : 5,
     b : 6,
     c : 7
}
```

I want to set zero to every object properties using [`angular.forEach()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach):

```js
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    value = 0;
});
```

I displayed their values using `console.log()` and I found out that **none of them are zero**.

but when I do

```js
obj.a = 0;
obj.b = 0;
obj.c = 0;
```

Their values are zero.

Can anyone explain about this?

Comment: You're just assigning the parameter.  You can't actually do that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just assigning the `value` parameter a value of `0`.

Access each property on the object with the `key` parameter:

```
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    obj[key] = 0;
});
```